# How to web scrape data (div) with reference to a second website?

Tags: html, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a page with beautiful soup and selenium. Whenever I inspect the page to identify the elements I want to retrieve I found them with no problem, see here for the elements I want as they appear in the html code:

```
<div class="full-date">
                    <span class="day-of-week ng-binding">Thursday</span> | 
                    <span class="month ng-binding">August</span>
                    <span class="date ng-binding">04, </span>
                    <span class="year ng-binding">2022</span>
                </div>
```

I need month, date and year. As you can see the elements are in an tree (div) so I use this line of code to get all div in the web:

```
divs = soup.find_all('div')
```

I print divs and all the info seems to be there however when I look for the month, date or year in the "span" I get this:

```
<div class="full-date">
 <span class="day-of-week">{{ WMService.auctionStartDate(lot.auction) | moment:'dddd' }}</span> | 
 <span class="month">{{ WMService.auctionStartDate(lot.auction) | moment:'MMMM' }}</span>
 <span class="date">{{ WMService.auctionStartDate(lot.auction) | moment:'DD' }}, </span>
 <span class="year">{{ WMService.auctionStartDate(lot.auction) | moment:'YYYY' }}</span>
 </div>
```

I do not get the actual data, as for example "August", "04" or "2022". It's like the html code refences to another code or page for this information, I am guessing that "WMService.auctionStartDate(lot.auction)"

Is this possible? How can I overcome this?

I highly appreciate your input on this

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Those elements are loading dynamically in page, so you need to wait them out, before locating them. One way to get your data with pure Selenium would be:

```
month = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='month ng-binding']")))
day = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='date ng-binding']")))
year = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='year ng-binding']")))
```

You would also need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Many thanks platipus_on_fire, this is very helpfull. I was actually thinking that those elements were dinamic but did not know how to tell or work with them, new on this. Many thanks for your time and advice!!!